# How to get back printed document?

Tags: printing, printer

A week ago I printed one very important document but hard copy of it was lost, also document was deleted from my PC.
Is there any possibility that this document is still saved somewhere (in print server, printer etc.)? I'd like to have this document back. My PC is connected to my company network and also printer is connected on the same network.

Thanks for any kind of answer

Comment: Scan the printout?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly unlikely, but not impossible - That said, recovery of it - if possible - will be very hard for you based on the question you are asking, so it may well be better to try recreate the document if possible.

It is possible that the deleted file still exists on your hard drive - and it might be possible to get it back using an undelete utility or, more likely photorec.  Problem with photorec will be it may recover nothing, one copy or multiple copies, and finding it will be hard as you will recover a lot of files but no filenames (only extensions).

It is conceivable that the printer has a built in hard drive, and a copy might exist on that.  If so, its a major to get to the data, as these things often don't have user serviceable parts.   If the printer is for a small office (ie something you bought off-the-shelf from a retail store), it is unlikely to have a hard drive.

You should speak to your network administrator as well - they will know more about your environment, and, if they are worth there salt, will have backups they can restore from.